# Infilling gaps of XYZ data consisting of no values with XYZ values of another dataset using GDAL

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w, xyz

I have 2 sets of XYZ data.

The first is this one:

[image]

and the second is this:

[image]

Evidently, the two XYZ datasets are 2 different surveys of the same area.
What I am trying to do is take dataset 2 and fill in the gaps of dataset 1. I want to keep the existing XYZ values of dataset 1 but where there is no data recorded, pull in the XYZ values of dataset 2.

I had tried doing it with gdal_calc and gdal_merge originally to try and create rasters of each and then combine them based on a single value, but this ended up being an entirely blank GeoTIFF.

How do I use GDAL to complete this task so that I can later write it into a Python script?

Comment: First you would need to establish the 2 data sets measured the same property and had the same levels. For example, using a quantile-quantile plot then proceeding to spatial similarity (e.g. plot of nearest neighbors, or interpolating both to a common grid).

Comment: In case you are dealing with bathymetry, you should first create both rasters, find their differences (ie. soundings) (eg. singlebeam.tif - multibeam.tif) and check if both data sets are in somehow similar (ie. no too obvios artifacts, especially the one based on singlebeam soundings). If things look good, I would just mix all sounding data sets in one XYZ file and get a unique raster.

Comment: Hi @Gery. Yes they are indeed multibeam and singlebeam surveys! What do you mean by mix all the sounding data sets? Is there perhaps a way of GDAL doing this?

Comment: Hello, I meant put all XYZ values in one file, in Linux simply write in a terminal `cat *.xyz > mynewxyzfile.xyz`

Comment: @Gery ah! I use a windows system. I also don't want the multibeam xyz data to overwrite the single beam xyz data. I want the multibeam data to fill in the spaces of the single beam

Comment: mmmmm not sure how to do that, it seems to be quite inaccurate thinking that the SB data set should have been acquired with a quite standard water sound velocity, while the MB data sets should have been more accurate according to a group of water sound velocity measurements (normally every day or less) plus additional adjustments (eg. patch tests, MRU for the swell). So, before filling in the SB extent (ie. areas without soundings) with the MB data set, I would check if no artifacts exist between both data sets (eg. both are in somehow 'leveled')

Comment: @Gery Yes I know it will be quite inaccurate but it has been requested, so it is more proof of concept it can be done. It is just achieving it that I am struggling with